# Android: Intermitent application flow issue

Tags: android

I'm facing with an intermittent application flow issue.
Here, I've got a Login screen where I'm able to login for the first time. But when I'm logging out and/or re-loging in, I'm unable to traverse further. As a work around, I need to uninstall my application and reinstall it and the flow is ok.

Can anyone please guide me on the possible issue.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
        GetWebServiceManager passwordExpiryWSManager = new GetWebServiceManager();

        //to check network connectivity (data connection/Wi-Fi)
        ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInformation = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInformation != null && networkInformation.isConnected() == true) {
            try {
//              passwordExpiryString = passwordExpiryWSManager.execute("http://172.25.164.143:8088/api/Login/GetExpiredPassword/?lContactKey=" + username.getText().toString()).get();
                passwordExpiryString = passwordExpiryWSManager.execute(AppConstants.URL + "/Login/GetExpiredPassword/?lContactKey=" + username.getText().toString()).get();

                jsonObjectPassExpiry = new JSONObject(passwordExpiryString);
                jsonArrayPassExpiry = jsonObjectPassExpiry.getJSONArray("LstLoginDetail");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*
             * Converting JSON string response from Webservice into Java Object
             * */
            if (jsonArrayPassExpiry != null) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                LoginTO[] loginExpTO = gson.fromJson(jsonArrayPassExpiry.toString(), LoginTO[].class);
                loginListPassExpiry = Arrays.asList(loginExpTO);
                intent = getIntent();

                if (loginListPassExpiry.get(0).getlSuccess() == 1) {
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PortfolioSummaryFragmentActivity.class);
//                  intent.putExtra("sToken", loginList.get(0).getsToken());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PasswordExpiryActivity.class);
//                  intent.putExtra("sToken", loginList.get(0).getsToken());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is not responding. Please try again later!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network connection unavailable. Please check your data plan or Wi-Fi connection!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**Logout.java**

```
public class LogoutActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView successResponse;
    private Intent intent;
    private Button btnLLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logout_success);

        successResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvwLSuccessMessage);
        btnLLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLLogin);

        intent = getIntent();
        successResponse.setText(intent.getStringExtra("successResponse"));
    }

    public void Login(View v) {
        btnLLogin.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "I'm unable to traverse further" do you mean that the startActivity() methods don't execute... or they do but don't work. Also you really need to liberally add some Log.d("I am here XXX"); statements to help yourself out with debugging these situations.

Comment: where are you calling Login(View v) in yours code?

Comment: please do some home work with http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1874864

Comment: @robnick: Thanks for your reply. What I actually meant by "I'm able to traverse further" was that the startActivity() method don't seem to execute or don't work. Can you help me?

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay: Login(View v) is linked to a button's attribute `onClick="Login"`

Comment: You need to add in logging so that you can see if you are hitting the startActivity() methods. Also are those toasts popping up saying service / network not available etc? Even add Toasts() before doing the start activity will help.

Answer (score 1):

please use `intent = new Intent(LogoutActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);` instead of `intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);`

beside this use
most important
Add `android:launchMode="singleTask "` to the activity element in your manifest for Activity `LoginActivity`

Comment: Sorry to bother you with questions but can you please explain why I would require to use this
`intent = new Intent(LogoutActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);`

Comment: it is always better to use current context and LogoutActivity.this is good to use, this reference is about to use currently running object. so do not so much bother it..but try with android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: I've already got `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in my manifest file. And moreover, when I reopen the Login screen, I've got the values pre-populated that I had used earlier. Is this the root cause of my intermittent issue?

Comment: I tried your solution/suggestion. I'm still facing with the same issue. So long I wasn't getting this issue reproduced. Yesterday when my manager was testing my application on his device, he couldn't go to the next screen after entering the correct credentials. We also verified that the webservices are getting hit properly. Any help?